# XSLT remove processed/select unprocessed data from original file

Tags: xslt, saxon

Hi I'm processing huge file (50k of lines) and need to know about nodes which were not processed. 
I was thinking about this solutions:

- create copy of processing file and when matching template is found, then remove it from copied file
- create "reverse template" of all templates and select all what was not processed (this probably won't work)
- process file normally and then create diff between original file and file created with this template.

So what is the best approach for this? If there's need to provide more details, let me know please.

Here is my sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">

    <changeSet id="1" author="a">
        <createTable tableName="TABLE1">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="1-1" author="a">
        <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_TABLE1" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="4" author="A">
        <createTable tableName="TABLE4">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

here is xslt template:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="coreTables"
                  select="('TABLE1','TABLE2')"/>


    <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
        <!-- CORE-->
        <xsl:comment> CORE TABLES </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
        <xsl:comment>CORE SEQUENCES</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates
                select="changeSet[createSequence[starts-with(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') and substring-after(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') = $coreTables]]"/>
        <xsl:comment> CORE INDEXES </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[createIndex/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
        <xsl:comment> CORE FOREIGN CONSTRAINTS </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[addForeignKeyConstraint/@baseTableName=$coreTables]"/>
        <xsl:comment> CORE VIEWS </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[createView/@viewName=$coreTables]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I'm using xslt 2 and saxom 9.8he

Thanks

Comment: Consider to have each separate question explain the necessary details directly in the question. It is not possible from a link to a particular question and a text saying you have a "template like in" that question to understand in what way your huge file has data that "could not be processed". As you use Saxon 9.8 you have access to XSLT 3 where you can define `xsl:mode on-no-match="fail"` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-fail) to get notified about nodes not being processed by the explicit templates you have written. But I am not sure that is what you are after.

Comment: sorry for that, edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:comment> CORE TABLES </xsl:comment>
<xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
```

Do this, to save the elements selected

```
<xsl:variable name="tables" select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$tables" />
```

And similarly for other statements. Then to get the elements in your XML that have not been matched you can do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[not(some $set in ($tables | $sequences | $indexes | $fkeys | $views) satisfies $set is .)]" />
```

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <!-- CORE-->
    <xsl:comment> CORE TABLES </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="tables" select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$tables" />

    <xsl:comment>CORE SEQUENCES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="sequences" select="changeSet[createSequence[starts-with(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') and substring-after(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') = $coreTables]]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sequences"/>

    <xsl:comment> CORE INDEXES </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="indexes" select="changeSet[createIndex/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$indexes"/>

    <xsl:comment> CORE FOREIGN CONSTRAINTS </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="fkeys" select="changeSet[addForeignKeyConstraint/@baseTableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$fkeys"/>

    <xsl:comment> CORE VIEWS </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="views" select="changeSet[addForeignKeyConstraint/@baseTableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$views"/>

    <xsl:comment> UNMATCHED </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[not(some $set in ($tables | $sequences | $indexes | $fkeys | $views) satisfies $set is .)]" />
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: Thanks to Martin Honnen, the final expression can be simplified to this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet except ($tables, $sequences, $indexes, $fkeys, $views)" />
```

Comment: Is `changeSet[not(some $set in ($tables | $sequences | $indexes | $fkeys | $views) satisfies $set is .)` not simpler expressed as `changeSet except ($tables, $sequences, $indexes, $fkeys, $views)`?

Comment: Yes. I was hoping you would come along and provide a simpler expression for me :)

Comment: Thanks both of you...hope my last question. Can I write that unmatched section to separate file?

Comment: Yes. Read up on [xsl:result-document](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "not processed". Do you mean "not selected by any call on xsl:apply-templates"? That's not the same thing, of course, a node might be processed using xsl:for-each, etc. Also, I suspect you're only interested in elements that weren't "processed" in this way, not in other nodes such as attributes and namespaces.

One approach that might (or might not) meet your requirements is to write a TraceListener. If you attach a TraceListener to your transformation, it will be notified every time an instruction changes the context item (that's another definition of "being processed"). Your TraceListener can then build a Java Set containing all nodes that were touched, and can then difference this with the set of all nodes on completion of processing.